# Revisions function ¿disabled?

Tags: revisions

In which version of wordpress was it implemented that the revisions to the posts will be saved. I need a version without that function or disable it- thanks

Comment: Perhaps you take a look [here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/#disable-post-revisions), you are looking for `WP_POST_REVISIONS`.

Comment: excelent- Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to run old versions of WordPress. Fortunately, you can quite easily turn off post revisions by using the [`wp_revisions_to_keep`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_revisions_to_keep/) filter.

Add the following code snippet to [a plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/), or to your active theme's `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter( 'wp_revisions_to_keep', 'wpse_368635_disable_revisions' );
function wpse_368635_disable_revisions( $revisions ) {
    // Setting the value to 0 will disable revisions.
    return 0;
}
```

This will disable post revisions, except for a single autosave. See [Revisions](https://wordpress.org/support/article/revisions/) for more information.